# Pointer typecasting with and without reference

Tags: c++, casting

Given that `A* pA;` and `B* pB;`, is there **ANY** difference between below type castings (query for all C++ style casts):

```
pB = reinterpret_cast<B*>(pA);      // pointer
pB = reinterpret_cast<B*&>(pA);     // pointer-reference
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two are radically different, at least in theory (and possibly on
a few rare machines, in practice).  The first takes a pointer to A, and
converts it to a pointer to B; in theory, at least, this may involve
changes in size and representation.   (I've actually worked on machines
where `char*` was larger than `int*`.  I rather doubt that any such
machines still exist, although perhaps in the embedded world...)  The
second is really the equivalent of `*reinterpret_cast<B**>(&pA)`; it
takes the bits in `pA`, and tells the compiler to interpret them as
a `B*`.  If the format is different, tough luck, and if the size is
different, you're likely to only access part of `pA` or to access memory
which isn't part of `pA`.

Also, the first is an rvalue, the second an lvalue.  Thus, something
like:

```
++ reinterpret_cast<B*>( pA );
```

is illegal, but:

```
++ reinterpret_cast<B*&>( pA );
```

isn't.  This is a useful technique for obfuscating code, and getting
unaligned pointers, pointers into the middle of objects, or other
pointers you don't dare dereference.

In general, the second form should be avoided, but there are rare
exceptions.  Posix guarantees that all pointers, including pointers to
functions (but not pointers to members—Posix specifies a C ABI,
which doesn't have pointers to members), have the same size and format,
so the second form is guaranteed to work.  And it is the only way you
can legally convert the `void*` returned by `dlsym` into a pointer to
a function:

```
int (*pf)( int );
reinterpret_cast<void*&>( pf ) = dlsym( handle, "functionName" );
```

(In C, you'd write:

```
int (*pf)( int );
*(void**)( &pf ) = dlsym( handle, "functionName" );
```

, see the
[official
specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/).)  Such tricks allow conversions between pointer types
which aren't otherwise allowed, but depends on additional guarantees not
in the standard.

Answer (score 1):

`reinterpret_cast` is implementation-defined. So in theory results can be different, but in practice you can assume that results will be the same because `typeid(B*)` is equal to `typeid(B*&)` => actually you casting to same type in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

There is **No** difference.

```
pB = reinterpret_cast<B*>(pA);      // pointer
```

is casting to a pointer of the type `B*` and

```
pB = reinterpret_cast<B*&>(pA);     // pointer-reference
```

is casting to reference to a pointer.

Note: there is no such thing as pointer to reference.

Comment: In his question OP already mentioned that first one is pointer and second one is reference to pointer.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan: OP said `Pointer-Reference`, there is no such thing is there? There can be only reference to pointer.

Comment: `Pointer-reference` in English is same as `reference of pointer` and not `pointer to reference`.

Comment: @Mihran Hovsepyan: Good English.

Answer (score 0):

No **functional** difference whatsoever.

There's obviously a maintainability difference if you'd use the latter variant. Your peers would think you had smoked something.  ;-)